# Do The Puppet Masters duplicate people?

Tags: novel, the-puppet-masters

In the story *The Puppet Masters* (not the movie, I've never watched it) we have a scenario early in the tale where they visit the Des Moines news office, the director "Barnes" proves to be parasite ridden and is killed to obtain a sample.

Later he is somehow seen alive on a video link, still later they return to the same office and get into a fight, "Barnes" is again involved and again gets killed.

Is any explanation that I might have missed given for this? Could the parasites re-animate? (This could be tricky for them because in the first encounter he had his legs shot off)

Comment: Even at the time they encounter "Barnes" again, they don't believe it's actually Barnes; the book refers to him as "Barnes number two."

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**No: The second Barnes is faked using human technology, not a duplicating ability of the aliens**

There's a brief allusion to the advances in disguise that the Old Man's section has access to:

> Only Cosmetics Records knows the original appearance of an agent—and
> they won’t talk.

Since "Barnes" was the head of a major broadcasting studio, and almost everyone there is hag-ridden, I think we are supposed to assume that the fake Barnes is someone with the same build as the real (dead) Barnes, who has been disguised to appear as much as possible to the real one, so that he can fool non-possessed people by stereo (and in person until the in-person folks can be possessed).

Note the Sam, Mary and the Old Man show no concern after this incident about a duplication ability of the slugs - they apparently figured out that the second Barnes was not an unearthly copy, but rather a use of familiar earthly techniques.

Comment: I've accepted the answer because I can't see anything in the book that counters it - but making the readers assume stuff is a bit of a Heinlein con IMO!